# Max concurrent http requests in http-kit's client?

Tags: java, clojure, http-kit

I'm using [http-kit](http://http-kit.org/)'s [client](http://http-kit.org/client.html), with asynchronous callbacks.

I wanted to know if there's a way to set a limit on the number of concurrent outgoing http requests, so that the waiting state for the callbacks doesn't cause an Out-Of-Memory exception.

I'm asking because, at least in theory, there might be too many concurrent, incompleted requests, that consume memory. Since memory is a limited resource (think about running in a container such as [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)), this might be an issue.

I know that increasing the available RAM is an option, but I'd like to know if there's a relevant limit that can be set.

Comment: Surely you could rate-limit the requests yourself from outside http-kit's client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none right now. Given that you want to use it in an async way, I don't think you are going to be able to use any lib and you will need to roll your own. Probably you can take inspiration on [Throttler](https://github.com/brunoV/throttler) or similar.